Change negative number display of pandastable from scientific to decimal
I have a Pandas dataframe with positive and negative numbers that I want to display via pandastable.
Positive numbers are displayed in decimal format, e.g. 1500.00, but negative numbers are displayed in scientific notation. All numbers in the underlying dataframe are rounded to two decimal places and displayed correctly when shown in the console. What could be the issue?
I tried setting display.float_format for Pandas, but the table will not change.

You could use lambda to format each number in the values column, to override pandastaple then you do table.show() just to display the table

try setting 'pd.set_option('display.float_format', '{:.2f}'.format)'
